# Query non existing custom object

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I'm on a developer org on which I have a managed package that I manually install on customers orgs. Each customer's org is a bit different, with different requests/requirements. The code is as universal/dynamic as possible but this time I have a request to link Events sobjs to a custom Object, which I must do from code.
Question is how do I do this w/o copying the object on my dev org, I don't want to include it in a RELEASED MANAGED PACKAGE for obvious reasons. I'm fiddling with 'dynamic' SOQL but a simple query returns a `List<Object>`. Object doesn't have a `get` method so I can't get the Id of that object.

Is there any other way to get the Id of that custom object that I don't want to have on my org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queries to SObjects should always return a `List<SObject>`. The SObject instance has an `Id` property, so you can access the id by instance like `record.Id`.

You should use [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) and [DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) in all instances to avoid pulling the objects into your package. It would be advisable to create custom objects in your developer/packaging org that mimic the objects on your target orgs, that way you can do proper tests on functionality.

I have also seen this type of construct too, though will entirely depend on what you're trying to do:

```
if(UserInfo.getOrganizationId() == devOrgId)
{
    return [SELECT Id FROM Fake_Object__c];
}
else
{
    return Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Real_Object__c');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I didn't knew what an SObject is, or that `Database.query` returns a list of SObjects. So now that I have `get()` I can do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing me a little, but maybe just some general advice will get you where you need to be...

First, the confusion: You said "I'm fiddling with 'dynamic' SOQL but a simple query returns a `List<Object>`. Object doesn't have a get method so I can't get the Id of that object.". Well, a dynamic query will return `List<sObject>` where each element does have a get method, so I don't understand what you mean here.

For managed packages, a good method to deal with custom objects (and even classes) which you don't know about in advance is to use Custom Metadata Types.

These are a bit like Custom Settings and would allow you to install your package onto an org, and then add entries to you Custom Metadata Type to declare what the Custom Object you're interested in is called in that particular org.

Inside your managed package, query the Custom Metadata Type to build an appropriate query and then you're off! You do have to be careful about Namespaces (and, IME, they're hard to test without making/installing the package).

Here's some sample code I used for a managed package where some object my package doesn't know about represents an action which can be delayed. My package has a scheduled to query those objects, then activate them if they need activation. First, I query the Custom Metadata Type:

```
List<Delayed_Action__mdt> delayedActionSpecs = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel,
                                                        Date_Time_Field__c,
                                                        Next_Status__c,
                                                        Waiting_Status__c,
                                                        Status_Field__c,
                                                        Object_Developer_Name__c,
                                                        Batch_Size__c
                                                        FROM Delayed_Action__mdt];
```

Then, I create a batch for each one:

```
DelayedActionBatch dab = new DelayedActionBatch(
                thisDelayedAction.Object_Developer_Name__c,
                thisDelayedAction.Status_Field__c,
                thisDelayedAction.Waiting_Status__c, 
                thisDelayedAction.Next_Status__c,
                thisDelayedAction.Date_Time_Field__c);

            Database.executeBatch(dab, (Integer)thisDelayedAction.Batch_Size__c);
```

Where the batch class's start method does the dynamic SOQL

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();

        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE ' + statusField +  ' = \'' + waitingStatus + '\' '
            + 'AND ' + dateTimeField + ' <= :now'
        );
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, apparently I didn't knew what an SObject is. I thought it's only SF's standard objects, not including custom ones. Finding out about this from the previous answer, I already coded what needed to be done. I only needed basic info from the custom object, something simpler than what you suggested (but I'll be sure to use your approach if the need arises). Now I'm waiting for approval to test and see if it works.